# How to create JSon object and store data in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I am trying to consume data from an API using REST call . I've succeeded to get data from the API .
I am having different rest call , I created different function for everyone .
I would like to know if I can store these data using JSon

it works perfect and gets all the Rest call but I would like to store them in JSon objects data to get it as a result in order to show it .

What I have done . 
- I created a new object called Json
- I looped to consume data using REST call .
- but whenever I got this data , I have problems to store them .

```
 var jsonObj = []; //declare object

         $.each(data.results, function(i,item){ // on this line

              jsonObj.push({id:item.conceptUuid , 

                  MedicalImage: item.dataURI ,
                  title: item.title ,
                  description: item.description ,


                 });
             $htmlstring.append($('<li/>').append($('<img/>').attr('src',jsonObj.MedicalImage)   ));
        $htmlstring.append("<div class='title'> title: " + jsonObj.title 
          + "<br> description : "+ jsonObj.description +

            "</div>")
          });

           $('#result').html($htmlstring);
```

The function should take a query string as an argument, and the server returns data as JSON.

Can you show me an example how to do this using jQuery Storing data in JSON object to avoid multiple calls ?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON object.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Looks correct -- can you post the actual response ("item"), and any error message you can see in the console?

Answer (score 0):

JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation". It is a format designed for serialized network transport, not for runtime memory storage. Inside JavaScript a JSON object is simply an object. The "Object Notation" part describes the fact that even though JSON is transferred as a string over the network, it's structure can still be read — both by software and humans — as a regular, plain JS object.

In example, `JSON.stringify({foo:'one', bar:'two'})` would return `'{"foo":"one", "bar":"two"}'`, a string representation of the JavaScript object ready for HTTP transfer. Likewise, calling `JSON.parse('{"foo":"one", "bar":"two"}')` on receiving end would convert it back to the original object structure with datatypes intact. Read more about JSON [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Other than this suspected misunderstanding of what JSON is and isn't, I'm not really sure what you mean by save. I take it you are haveing trouble *reading* the data and not getting anything on screen. This could be due to a number of things, primarily:

1. You might not be working with a de-serialized JSON string. In this case the `data` or `data.results` argument above might still be JSON, in which case you need to call `JSON.parse(data)` on it first in order to iterate over the properties of the data object.
2. You might be trying to use out-of-scope variables since you are dealing with already existing variables (`$htmlstring`) inside of the success callback. If so you should read up on the [JavaScript scope model](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)

If none of this helps, I recommend you open up the JavaScript console in your browser, run the code and check for error messages. If any, you should post them here to better your chances of a good answer.

Good luck!